# Convert List from java to a dropdown menu in html

Tags: java, html, jira-rest-java-api

I have output from a java code in the form of a list

```
public class getProjectList {
    final String username = "username";
    final String password = "password";
    final String ProjectNames = null;

    public getProjectList() throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        final URI jiraserverURI = new URI("https://jira.xxxx.com");
        final JiraRestClientFactory restClientfactory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        final JiraRestClient restClient =
          restClientfactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraserverURI,username,password);
        final Iterable<BasicProject> allproject = restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().get();
        final String ProjectNames = allproject.toString();
        System.out.println(ProjectNames);
    }
}
```

I want to use the output from this code as a dropdown menu item. Need help with this. Thank You

Comment: `String option = "<option value=\"\">Volvo</option>" + value + "\">" + value + "</option>";` as way... and further in loop ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String projectsToHtmlOptions(String projectNames,String separator){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("<select>");
   for(String project:projectNames.split(separator)
      sb.append("<option value=\""+project+"\">"+project+"</option>");
   sb.append("</select>");
   return sb.toString();
}
```